# Map doesn't appear with custom CartoDB query

Tags: carto

I'm trying to use CartoSQL from CartoDB.js to create a layer. Here is the SQL query I am trying to make:

```sql
SELECT 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed.flood, 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed.the_geom 
FROM 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed
```

All the columns are in the table –– I checked. [This is the query string](http://bit.ly/1gLN1sh) and you should see the same error I am seeing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, there is an important piecing missing that is needed by our map tiler, the `the_geom_webmercator` column. Change your query to this and it will work,

```
SELECT 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed.flood, 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed.the_geom,
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed.the_geom_webmercator 
FROM 
  rpa_nj_hsip_hospitals_compressed
```

**What is the_geom_webmercator?**

In CartoDB there is a hidden column on all of your tables called the_geom_webmercator. It automatically turns anything in the_geom into a webmercator projected geometry. If you change a value in the_geom, it will change in the_geom_webmercator without you needing to do anything. It helps make you maps fast, but it also means you need to include it in custom queries.

**What about queries that modify the_geom on the fly?**

Say you are doing something like an ST_Buffer on the_geom. You just need to transform the result to webmercator and alias the result to the_geom_webmercator. So take the query,

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(the_geom, 0.01) the_geom FROM table_name
```

You would do,

```
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(the_geom, 0.01),3857) the_geom_webmercator FROM table_name
```

And now it would show up on the map. `ST_Transform(geometry, SRID)` reprojects geometries. `3857` is the SRID of the web mercator projection

Comment: cartodb_id column also must be selected for the query to work.

Comment: yep, it is good practice to include cartodb_id because it is needed whenever there is interactivity

Comment: @andrewxhill I'm having this same issue, but can't get a query with ST_Area to work. Is this what I should be doing?

SELECT * 

, round((ST_Area(the_geom::geography)*(0.000247105))::numeric, 2) as Acres 
, the_geom_webmercator
, cartodb_id

FROM ood_newdevelopments_3785

Comment: close, "*" selects all the columns, so the_geom_webmercator is already in there. if you list it a second time it will give you an err. same for cartodb_id. here, SELECT * , round((ST_Area(the_geom::geography)*(0.000247105))::numeric, 2) as Acres FROM ood_newdevelopments_3785

Comment: Ok it seems to be working, but the query is exactly the same as it was before I changed it, which is weird... did something change behind the scenes in the last week or so that prompted this issue and the one that started this thread? Thanks, @andrewxhill!!!