# Why aren't the info windows showing up on my cartodb layers?

Tags: carto

I made a cartodb map with 2 layers. The layers draw from the same table but I use filters to display some of the data in one layer and some of the data in another.  Without the layers my info windows were working and now they're not.  I'm not sure how to start troubleshooting this.

The SQL expression on layer 1 is `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE useful_column > 0` and on layer 2 it is  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE useful_column IS NULL` -- the goal is to use a different info window altogether on the regions where `useful_column` has no data.

Comment: If you're using a custom filter, I take that to mean you're using a custom SQL expression, and I've run into the issue described here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88265/map-doesnt-appear-with-custom-cartodb-query in which you also need to select tableName.the_geom_webmercator in order for the features to display.

Comment: @mapBaker I added some detail (I'm trying to help troubleshoot this). The queries both select `*` -- which should include `the_geom_webmercator`, no?

Comment: Yes, * should include the_geom_webmercator. Please, can you send a link the the map?

Comment: @Amanda I will leave this in javisantana's capable hands...